# DataSet.Load(reader) error "Table TableName does not belong to this DataSet."

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

i am trying to fill dataset (more then one datatables from db in one go) using *system.data.common.dbcommand.* but not successful. I am getting error "Table ***TableName*** does not belong to this DataSet."

Note: ***TableName*** is name of datatable. Here is my code, please guide and help me.

```
dbCommand = DBHelper.CreateCommand("SPName");
    DataTable EmailMessage=new DataTable ();
    DataTable EmailContact=new DataTable ();
    DataTable EmailAttachment=new DataTable ();
    EmailAttachment.TableName = "EmailAttachment";
    EmailContact.TableName = "EmailContact";
    EmailMessage.TableName = "EmailMessage";

    DataTable[] tables = {EmailMessage,EmailContact,EmailAttachment};
    DataSet ds= DBHelper .ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand,tables);





public static DataSet  ExecuteDataSet(DbCommand command,DataTable[] tables)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        foreach (DataTable dt in tables)
        {
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);            
        }
        try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            ds = new DataSet ();
            ds.Load (reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges,tables);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
        finally
        { command.Connection.Close(); }
        return ds;
    }
```

I have consulted http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5fd1ahe2.aspx but couldn't get where I am wrong. Please help me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

you are overriding the dataset definition in this code block

```
 try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            **ds = new DataSet ();**
            ds.Load (reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges,tables);
        }
```

put it in this way:

```
try
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            //**ds = new DataSet ();**
            ds.Load (reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges,tables);
        }
```

greetings!!

Answer (score 0):

Check the overloads of the ds.Tables.Add method. Make sure when you add the table, a table name is being specified, otherwise it might just add it with a default name, such as 'TableName'.

Good luck!

Comment: Adam I am mentioning name in my code. By the way where this will make a difference ?

Answer (score -2):

Just a comment (Needed more room!) -

Please don't do this:

```
...
catch (Exception ex)
{ throw ex; }
...
```

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/exceptionbestpractices.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx

Comment: @jTC This is very valid criticism.